# C++ iterator problems

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following member data

```
vector<State<T>*> activeChildren;
```

I want to clean-up these pointers in my destructor

```
StateContainer<T>::~StateContainer() {
    vector<State<T>*>::iterator it =
        activeChildren.begin();
    while(it!=activeChildren.end()) {
        State<T>* ptr = *it;
        it = activeChildren.erase(it);
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

I get the following error from g++ 4.3.2 on Ubuntu:

```
./fsm2/StateContainer.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual ervan::StateContainer<T>::~StateContainer()’:
../fsm2/StateContainer.cpp:24: error: expected `;' before ‘it’
../fsm2/StateContainer.cpp:25: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? I get this error in two more places where I use iterator loops, but not when I use for_each(...)

Comment: Looks like a good place to use boost::ptr_vector<State<T> >

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like typename time again - I think you need:

```
typename vector<State<T>*>::iterator it = ...
```

A heuristic for g++ users - when you see this message in template code:

```
expected `;' before ‘it’
```

it is a pretty good bet that the thing in front of the 'it' is not being seen by the compiler as a type and so needs a 'typename' added.

Comment: We met last time on my question for which the answer was *ding* *ding* typename! ;)

Comment: Well I did try to find errors like this one before I asked, but g++ doesn't exactly give good errors. I've never actually learn c++, I just use what I've picked up along the way.

Comment: @kts: I don't think you could be expected to find an answer by searching - you'd pretty much have to know the answer to come up with a reasonable search query.

Answer (score 5):

It's a parsing issue. In this code, `vector<State<T>*>::iterator` is a nested dependent type.

Until you know what T is (and T isn't known at parse time), the parser/compiler doesn't realize that iterator is a type (could be a static member variable, for all it knows).

Therefore, you must prefix the definition with typename as a hint to tell the compiler that for all `vector<State<T>*>`, `vector<State<T>*>::iterator` is a type name.